# Accessing EnvDTE80.ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder produces an Interop error

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.7.5 
I start a new VSIX project and add an AsyncPackage.
Then I add the following line to the bottom of the InitializeAsync method.

var v = EnvDTE80.ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder;

I get a red squiggle under ProjectKinds and the following error:

Interop type 'ProjectKinds' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

I look at the reference for EnvDTE80 and the "Embed Interop Types" is set to false.

So why do I get this error?

Comment: Does the project have NuGet packages in the References node? Which ones?

Comment: Yes: CoreUtility 15.0.26201, Imaging 15.0.26201, Imaging.Interop.14.0.DesignTime 14.3.25408,
OLE.Interop 7.10.6071, SDK.EmbedInteropTypes 15.0.10, Shell.15.0 - 15.0.26201,Shell.Framework 15.0.26201, Shell.Interop 7.10.6071, Shell.Interop.10.0 - 10.0.30319,Shell.Interop.11.0 - 11.0.61030, Shell.Interop.12.0 - 12.0.30110,Shell.Interop.14.0.DesignTime 14.3.25407, Shell.Interop.8.0 - 8.0.50727,Shell.Interop.9.0 - 9.0.30729, TextManager.Interop 7.10.6070,
TextManager.Interop.8.0 - 8.0.50727, Threading 15.0.240, Utilities 15.0.26201,
Validation 15.0.82
VSSDK.BuildTools 15.7.104

Comment: Same problem for `WindowKinds`

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK.EmbedInteropTypes to latest version 15.0.27. There was a bug in older versions that I reported to Microsoft that caused it to embed types of EnvDTE80, which is not possible because it contains classes. See comments on post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/10/10/simplify-extension-development-with-packagereference-and-the-vssdk-meta-package/

Comment: That is issue. Thank you so much for taking time to help!